# Download Excel File From Server - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, get, angular7

Trying to download excel (.xlsx) file from my restAPI.

This is my code -

```
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats');
      this.http
        .get(
          `${pathToExcel}`,
          { headers: headers, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }
        )
        .subscribe((res: any) => {
          let blob = new Blob([res._body], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats' });
            let myUrl = document.createElement('a');
            myUrl.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            myUrl.download = 'Log.xlsx';
            let event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
            event.initEvent('click', true, true);
            myUrl.dispatchEvent(event);
        });
```

The file is downloaded but it's empty.
What am I missing?

Comment: What is a content of `res.body`?

Comment: �~nL_rels/PK�~nL    docProps/PK �~nLxl/PK �~nL  xl/_rels/PK �~nL xl/theme/PK �~nLxl/worksheets/PK